# Build an net461 app includ framework dlls in build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

when I build a class library build of the 4.6.1 framework it includes in the build all the dll of the framework that I use, but I imagine that the dlls that already are of the framework should not be generated for the build folder, can help me ?

[image: these dlls are from the framework]

[image: Project propert]

[image: References]

Comment: my question is, how not to include those dlls that should be used by the framework installed on the machine

Comment: I added one more image to the question so that you see the project framework

Comment: I removed the Microsoft.Extensions.etc references from the nuget and that solved the problem, some of the packages should accuse dependency of the .netstandard, which in turn brought all the dlls of the framework built on it

Comment: Ah - sometimes you just need to ask for help - then you solve your own problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the Microsoft.Extensions.etc references from the nuget and that solved the problem, some of the packages should accuse dependency of the .netstandard, which in turn brought all the dlls of the framework built on it

Comment: You could mark it now, thanks for your sharing again.

Answer (score 0):

Select the reference in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. When you slect it, the properties should appear below the solution explorer.

Change the 'Copy Local' to false.

Comment: copy local is flag to false

Comment: ... and not all of these dlls appear in the references, see the new image

Comment: I removed the Microsoft.Extensions.etc references from the nuget and that solved the problem, some of the packages should accuse dependency of the .netstandard, which in turn brought all the dlls of the framework built on it